# passing an array into a function from within a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to pass this arr into a function, one element at a time. I have more work to do beyond that, but I cannot even get it to send the element to the `square` function, so this is just a hurdle that I don't understand? Anyway, this is the code:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

function square(element){
    return element * element;
}

function applyFunction(arr, square){
    for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; ++i){
        alert(square(arr[i]));
    }
}

applyFunction(arr,square());
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I am sure this is simple for you guys.

Comment: Change `applyFunction(arr,square());` to `applyFunction(arr,square);`

Comment: `square` is the function, `square()` runs the function `square` and returns the result.

Comment: @dystroy, please post as answer. http://jsbin.com/magahima/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Modify your last line from

```
applyFunction(arr,square());
```

to

```
applyFunction(arr,square);
```